# Can't upload screenshots to publish my application in google developer console

Tags: android, upload, google-play, screenshot, publish

I spent my whole day trying to upload screenshots of my newly created application.
Every time I try to upload a phone screenshot (PNG - 24bit 1920x1080px) it shows an error: 'You should check your screenshot is a valid image'...

Am I doing something wrong or is this a common issue? How do i fix this?

**Edit**

It is working now, repeating the same process. I guess the developer console wasn't working correctly during the entire day untill now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could your image possibly have an alpha channel? The Google Play graphic asset guidelines also state that 24bit PNGs must not have an alpha channel.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en

Requirements:

- JPEG or 24-bit PNG **(no alpha)**
- Minimum dimension: 320px
- Maximum dimension: 3840px
- The maximum dimension of your screenshot can't be more than twice as long as the minimum dimension.

Comment: No because i even used Gimp to export as .png, where I explicitly asked to 'remove alpha channel'...

Comment: Yeah okay, then it must be the console like you said, especially since you got it to work after a while.

Comment: Exactly. But your suggestion is important to other publishers because if u do not remove the alpha channel, it will not be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody else facing issues uploading screenshots:
If they don't even show after uploading them try using incognito mode, and if you're getting size errors try capturing the screenshots using the emulator in the android studio.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone sees a message that includes 2:1 || 1:2 , make sure the size in pixels of your image follows this relation.

For example, 321x5499, it doesn't follow the maximum resolution ratio of 1:2, which says that the maximum width can be twice the maximum height:

321x642  <- Maximum Dimensions of the image.
321x643  <- 1 Pixel above the maximum accepted dimension

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For me, I simply switched to Chrome. Safari worked for most screenshots but not for the phone screenshots.